# Does IN (NULL) consistently return no rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a system which builds T-SQL queries from objects. This system deliberately throws exception if trying to use empty lists for `IN()` condition.

I am thinking of replacing this behaviour with `IN (NULL)` operation.
From what I tried, this returns no rows, even for values which are null.

This is ideal behavior for my situation.

But in MS documentation, there is this remark:

> Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

Can `IN (NULL)` be used to consistently return no rows? Is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: The "unexpected" behaviour tends to be with `NOT IN`; specifically `NOT IN ({Values containing NULL})` will *always* evaluate to `UNKNOWN`. `IN ({Values containing NULL})` however, will evaluate to `TRUE` is at least one non-`NULL` value matches the value of a non-`NULL` value in the `IN`. `SELECT V.I FROM (VALUES(1),(2))V(I) WHERE V.I IN (1,NULL);` returns `1`, however, `SELECT V.I FROM (VALUES(1),(2))V(I) WHERE V.I NOT IN (1,NULL);` returns *no* rows (not `2`).

Comment: I would tend to assume the documentation mentions both for a reason, but using `except / intersect` is a reliable alternative as it uses an *is null* comparision instead of equality.

Comment: Rather than trying to build a dynamic query from an `IN` list (which has problems around SQL injection and plan reuse), use a Table Valued Parameter, for example `WHERE YourTable.Column IN (SELECT tvp.Column FROM @TVP tvp)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes with hindsight I would agree and retract comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Column] IN (NULL)` is equivalent to `[Column] = NULL`

In the default setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`, `[Column] = NULL` always returns an empty result set.

So, as long as you are interested in

> it returns no records even for values which are null [sic]

, it will work.

An argument is that this is obscure code, and anyone without that knowledge (and possibly even you after a few months) will possibly deem the non-returning of NULL valued rows as "unexpected", and might try to "fix" it.

Comment: "An argument is that this is obscure code...". This is why comments exist. Throw a comment in the code explaining a) what's going on and b) why that choice was made to make it clear to the next person (who may be the original author!).

Comment: @Ben Thul Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

Technically null cannot be compared with any other value(even not with null itself). From the second line of TSQL doc what you have stated clearly explains that is is a bad practice("Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results")